# how to set the setting of pd.get_dummies outcome is 0 and 1 not true/false

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

[What I run out is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUjLZ.png)

but what I want is this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMcFo.png)

Help me solve this.
I have tried using astype(int) to make the data become 1 and 0

but is not what I want.

I want the setting, in the future when I run it, I will auto come out 1 and 0 not true and false.